# Returning the index of max value in a list considering another list as a allowed index in python

Tags: python

I want to know the index of maximum element in list "b", considering list "a" which shows the available indexes of list "b". For example:

```
a = [1,3,4]
b = [20,15,13,60,50,40]
```

so considering maximum value among (15, 60, 50) the outcome must be the 3 (the index of element 60 in list b).

Comment: How did you approach it? Whats the code you have written?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `key` argument for `max`:

```
max(a,key = lambda i: b[i]) #3
```